# ActiveCampaign contactTags request returning bad request tag id not provided

Tags: c#, .net-core, activecampaign

I need to add a tag to a contact using API.

I’m using Active Campaign resources according to API V3 documentation (https://developers.activecampaign.com/reference#create-contact-tag), making a POST request. I've got other requests working like adding and getting contacts and adding and getting accounts the same way.

However, making the request i just receive a 400 Bad request status, including the error No tag id provided. I have checked both tag id and contact id exist.

I'm using this function to fill the contact tag, I checked and both are filled when sending.

```
    private void UpsertTag(GetAllTagsOutput output, string contactId, string tagvalue)
    {
        TagMeta tag = output.Tags.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Tag == tagvalue);
        ContactTag contactTag = new ContactTag
        {
            Contact = contactId,
            Tag = tag.Id            
        };

        this.service.Upsert(contactTag);
    }
```

The contacttag class looks like this:

```
[Api("contactTags")]
public class ContactTag : ActiveCampaignRef
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contact ID
    /// </summary>
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Tag ID
    /// </summary>
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Then i upsert it using

```
    public T Upsert<T>(T item, IDictionary<string, string> parameters = null) where T : ActiveCampaignRef
    {
        if (IsNestedObject(item))
        {
            return requestService.Post<T>(GetPath(item), item); 
        }

        var responseValues = requestService.Post<Dictionary<string, object>>(GetPath(item), item, parameters);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseValues[GetItemName(item)].ToString());
    }
```

The get path does return the expected path https://youraccountname.api-us1.com/api/3/contactTags

finally i got a post

```
    public TResponse Post<TResponse>(string path, object data, IDictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
    {
        return this.Send<TResponse>(path, "POST", data, parameters);
    }

    private TResponse Send<TResponse>(string path, string method, object data = null, IDictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(this.SendRequest(path, method, data, parameters));
    } 


    private string SendRequest(string path, string method, object data = null, IDictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
    {
        var finalPath = path;

        if (parameters != null && parameters.Any())
        {
            // Add parameters to the request
            var queryString = string.Empty;
            foreach (var param in parameters)
            {
                queryString = queryString + "&" + param.Key + "=" + param.Value;
            }
            finalPath += "?" + queryString;
        }

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + finalPath);
        request.Method = method;
        request.Headers.Add("API-Token", apiKey);

        AttachDataIfNecessary(request, data);

        try
        {
            var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (Stream dataStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                string response = reader.ReadToEnd();

                return response;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            throw GetActiveCampaignException(e);
        }
        
    }
```

Method: POST
Status: BadRequest
Response: {"errors":[{"title":"Invalid value for query parameter contactTag.tag","detail":"No tag id provided","source":{"parameter":"contactTag.tag"}}]}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was running into this issue (with php), and it took me quite a while to figure this out, but for me the problem is that there is a small bug in the documentation of the API, and at first I posted

`'body' => '{"contact":"1","tag":"2"}',`

when the needed body is:

`'body' => '{"contactTag":{"contact":"1","tag":"20"}}',`

I am not sure that this is exactly your error since you are creating this contactTag object, but I did get exactly the same error, and for me using the second body worked.